# Passing connection information to all nodes/mappers in HDInsight for a MapReduce job

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-hdinsight

I have a list of Azure Table Storage `partition keys` that are the inputs to Mappers. The idea is that each Mapper will get a different key to do its work on.

Is there a way to pass the `connection string` or `key` to the storage account without hard-coding it? In Batch, all you need to do is provide a job with an `EnvironmentSetting` and each node would get that variable. I know that the definition of `node` is very different here - for Batch they are VMs, and in HDInsight they are Hadoop nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is completely possible using Azure Script actions for both Linux & Windows. The Action script is run on every node and is meant to provide additional provisioning for a cluster - such as installing dependencies or, as in this case, providing connection details.

The scripts are the standard shell scripting language for each system (i.e. bash for Linux, Powershell for Windows) and as such are very easy to write.

### [For Linux-based nodes (bash)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-script-actions-linux):

```
echo "AZURE_CONNECTION_KEY=some_key_string" | sudo tee -a /etc/environment
```

### [For Windows-based nodes (Powershell)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-script-actions):

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('AZURE_CONNECTION_KEY', 'some_key_string', 'Machine');
```

Adding `Machine` ensures that the variable is machine-wide and not script-local.

### Update:

I found this method of passing variables to be very flakey. A python script worked locally using environmental variables but not on the cluster, despite the environmental variable actually existing.

Using a shared config (e.g. an ini file) seems to be the better option - and why not? You have full access to the blob service in HDInsight.